# Is multiprocessing.Queue.qsize() reliable if protected by multiprocessing.Lock?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to get elements from a multiprocessing.Queue only if it has at least N items:

```
def popn(n, q, lock):
  lock.acquire()
  ret = []
  if q.qsize() >= n:
    for i in range(n):
      ret.append(q.get())
  lock.release()
  return ret

def push(element, q, lock):
  lock.acquire()
  q.put(element)
  lock.release()
```

However, according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue:%7E:text=Return%20the%20approximate%20size%20of%20the%20queue.%20Because%20of%20multithreading/multiprocessing%20semantics%2C%20this%20number%20is%20not%20reliable), multiprocessing.Queue.qsize() is not reliable, I want to know whether it will be accurate size of the queue if I protect the queue with multiprocessing.Lock(as is shown in the code above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinda... but your code won't work on Mac, and on other platforms, you might deadlock.

First, Mac doesn't implement the `sem_getvalue` function needed to support `multiprocessing.Queue.qsize()`. On Mac, your code will fail with a `NotImplementedError`.

Second, if a queue is too full, `q.put` can block until something calls `get`. If you try to protect the queue with a lock, then it's impossible for that `get` call to happen, because the lock is being held by the process stuck in the middle of `put`. (This can happen even if you don't pass `maxsize`, although you're unlikely to run into this behavior without passing `maxsize` - the queue size would have to hit the semaphore implementation's `SEM_VALUE_MAX`, which I believe is very high on most systems.)

Answer (score 0):

> However, according to docs, multiprocessing.Queue.qsize() is not reliable, I want to know whether it will be accurate size of the queue if I protect the queue with multiprocessing.Lock(as is shown in the code above)?

"Reliable" is not the same thing as "accurate".  I expect `multiprocessing.Queue.qsize()` to be perfectly accurate if implemented.  Other than the possibility that it is not implemented, the problem the docs are refering to when they say "Because of multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this number is not reliable," is that if you're using it in a context in which multiple threads or multiple processes are manipulating the queue (which are exactly the situations where this particular queue makes sense), then you cannot be certain that the queue still has that size at whatever later time you decide what to do with the info.  Even if that's in the very next statement.

If you protect the queue against mutation between determining its size and acting on that information then you address the reliability problem, but you may cause yourself a deadlock issue as described in [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76910384/2402272).  You could consider addressing that by using `put_nowait(element)` or `put(element, False)` instead of `put(element)`.  Of course, *then* robustness demands that you be prepared for the possibility that the attempt to enqueue an element raises an exception.

You could consider instead gathering elements into groups of five, and enqueuing them in five-element lists.  If there is only one process enqueuing elements then you can do it directly in that process.  If you have multiple processes enqueuing elements then you could do it with *two* queues -- one on which the individual elements are enqueued and a second from which the 5-element bundles are dequeued.  In the middle would be another process that bundles elements from the first queue and enqueues the bundles on the second queue.  No locking is then required, nor any `qsize()` call.

Comment: The lock is protecting more than just the `qsize` call, so other processes can't actually affect the queue size while `popn` is using the return value (as long as no other code tries to access the queue unprotected).

Comment: That's a fair observation, @user2357112.  I shall address it.  But this is what the docs mean when they say "*Because of multithreading/multiprocessing semantics*, this number is not reliable."